# Separate multiple sections/lines from a file

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, awk, scripting

I have a file with below sample texts:

```
THIS(
is first
Line);
THAT(
is second line);
THIS(
is third
line);
THAT(
is 
fourth
line);
```

If you see the file, each sections are either starts with "THIS" or "THAT" and each section of texts are ending with a semicolon (`;`).
I want a Unix command/script which will search for both "THIS" and "THAT" and copy all "THIS" sections to a file `first_file`, and all "THAT" sections to a different file `second_file`.

Example:
The first file should contain:

```
THIS(
is first
Line);
THIS(
is third
line);
```

The second file should contain:

```
THAT(
is second line);
THAT(
is 
fourth
line);
```

Comment: Can you provide example of the input text?

Comment: In one line or they are in different lines?

Answer (score 3):

Given

```
$ cat thisthat 
THIS(
is first
Line);
THAT(
is second line);
THIS(
is third
line);
THAT(
is 
fourth
line);
```

then

```
awk -vRS=';\n' 'BEGIN{ORS=RS} /^THIS/ {print > "these"} /^THAT/ {print > "those"}' thisthat
```

results

```
$ head these those 
==> these <==
THIS(
is first
Line);
THIS(
is third
line);

==> those <==
THAT(
is second line);
THAT(
is 
fourth
line);
```

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for multi-char RS and no space after `-v`.

Answer (score 1):

With any awk:

```
$ awk -v RS=';' 'NF{sub(/^\n/,""); print > (/^THIS/ ? "first_file" : "second_file")}' file

$ cat first_file
THIS(
is first
Line)
THIS(
is third
line)

$ cat second_file
THAT(
is second line)
THAT(
is
fourth
line)
```

or with GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='(THIS|THAT)[^;]+;\n' -v ORS= '{$0=RT; print > (/^THIS/ ? "first_file" : "second_file")}' file

$ cat first_file
THIS(
is first
Line);
THIS(
is third
line);

$ cat second_file
THAT(
is second line);
THAT(
is
fourth
line);
```

Both solutions assume that your example is accurate and you never have `;`s except at the end of the blocks (e.g. not within the `(...)` parts).

Answer (score 0):

Using `ed` file editor but it requires that the second (empty) file be created before hand. The original file is named `file1` in this example.

Create the second file is named `file2`

```
> file2
```

The heredoc

```
ed -s file1 << 'EOF'
H
g/^THAT($/;/^.*\;$/d
w
u
g/^THIS($/;/^.*\;$/d
0r file2
w file2
EOF
```

First line which feeds `file1` to `ed` using a heredoc `ed -s file1 << 'EOF'`

Second line prints more verbose messages useful for errors. `H`

Third line Delete lines that starts with THAT( until the line that ends with a ;

```
g/^THAT($/;/^.*\;$/d
```

Fourth line Write the changes to file1 `w`

Fifth line Undo the changes ONLY in the buffer not the file1. `u`

Sixth line Delete lines that starts with THIS( until the line that ends with a ;

```
g/^THIS($/;/^.*\;$/d
```

Seventh line Add the remaining text in the buffer to the beginning of file2

```
0r file2
```

Eight line Write the changes file2. `w file2`

---

The one liner.

```
>file2; printf '%s\n' H 'g/^THAT($/;/^.*\;$/d' w u 'g/^THIS($/;/^.*\;$/d' '0r file2' 'w file2' | ed -s file1
```

Please note that `ed` edits the file `in-place` meaning files will be edited directly and it does not print the output to somewhere else, so test it first with some examples before running `ed` in your production file.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with Awk Flag method

```
awk '/THIS/{f=1}/THAT/{f=0}f' file > file1(Contains "THIS" PATTERN)
awk '/THAT/{f=1}/THIS/{f=0}f' file > file2(Contains "THAT" PATTERN)
```

output

```
cat file1

THIS(
is first
Line);
THIS(
is third
line);



cat file2

    THAT(
    is second line);
    THAT(
    is 
    fourth
    line);
```